# Verilog replication with macro

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a sys_defs.vh header file with the macro:

```
`define REG_WIDTH 5
```

and I'm trying to compare a bus of the same width like so:

```
input [2:0][`REG_WIDTH-1:0]           aregs_in,
...
if(aregs_in[i] != {`REG_WIDTH{1}})
  //do stuff
```

but I get the following warning when I try to simulate

> Warning-[CWUC] Concatenations with unsized constants.
>   An unsized constant '1' is used in the concatenation. The unsized
>   constant will be used as a 32-bit constant.

Basically I'm just trying to compare it to 111111 where the # of one's is macro-defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Verilog `1` by itself infers a 32-bit decimal with the value one. You want `1'b1` for a single bit.

```
input [2:0][`REG_WIDTH-1:0]           aregs_in,
...
if(aregs_in[i] != {`REG_WIDTH{1'b1}})
  //do stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

In Verilog you could do

```
   if(~&aregs_in[i]) //~& is the NAND operator
      // do stuff
```

In SystemVerilog, this would be more descriptive

```
  if(aregs_in[i] != '1) // '1 means 'fill with 1's'
      // do stuff
```